# Swift : Missing argument for parameter 'locale' in call

Tags: ios, swift

How to exactly define str as string in for loop ?

```
for str in aryFilters{

     var str1 : NSString=NSString(string: str)
     var filters : CIFilter=CIFilter(name: str1)  

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for str in arrayFilters as [String] {
    var str1 : NSString = NSString(string: str)
    var filters : CIFilter = CIFilter(name: str1)  
}
```